# When change scale button has diff height

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the [site](http://bastaprice.com/)

The problem is when press *Ctrl +*  or *Ctrl -* the "SEARCH" button has a different height than the search textfield. Please help me make the "SEARCH" button the same size as the search textfield when scaling (after pressing *Ctrl +* or *Ctrl -*).

Answer (score 0):

Use `em` as a unit, and make sure they both have the same overall height, including `height`, `padding` and `border`. If that doesn't fix it, check the `font-size` too.